Difference between "to add insult to injury" and "twist/turn the knife (in the wound)"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'to add insult to injury' and 'twist/turn the knife (in the wound)'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

to add insult to injury: said when you feel that someone has made a bad situation worse by doing something else to upset you
twist/turn the knife (in the wound): to make someone who is annoyed, worried, or upset feel even worse


The difference can be seen in the metaphors. One is "You hurt me, and then you insulted me!" It can be used broadly, but it would be used most perfectly when the first thing is really damaging but the second is just embarrassing or, well, insulting. The other is "You [or someone else!] attacked me, but this new thing was just meant to cause me extra pain."
